# How can I upgrade nuget packages in a controlled, less-impactful way?

Tags: c#, nuget

My code base right now uses the `Unity.Container` package at version 5.8.10. My goal is to upgrade this to 5.11.7. However, I also use `Unity.AspNet.WebApi` at version 5.0.15. When I upgrade `Unity.Container`, I get errors about `Unity.AspNet.WebApi` needing to be upgraded. So when I bump the version of *that* to 5.11.1, I now get build errors related to the ASP.NET packages (which I also use):

> Error NU1605 : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core from 5.2.7 to 5.2.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> MyLibrary.WebApiCommon.Tests -> MyLibrary.WebApiCommon -> Unity.AspNet.WebApi 5.11.1 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.7 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.7 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.2.7 && < 5.3.0)
> MyLibrary.WebApiCommon.Tests -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.2.6)

And:

> Error NU1605 : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi from 5.2.7 to 5.2.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> MyLibrary.RepositoryManagementApi -> Unity.AspNet.WebApi 5.11.1 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (>= 5.2.7)
> MyLibrary.RepositoryManagementApi -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (>= 5.2.6)

(There are a lot more but this should be enough to show the problem)

And if I upgrade these, I continue further down the rabbit hole: It complains about mixed versions of other things like `Microsoft.Owin`, `Newtonsoft.Json`, `System.Net.Http` packages, and so on. I stopped at some point because I was going absolutely insane. For a package manager this is all feels very poorly implemented. Either that or I'm doing something very wrong.

I'd like to know how I can simply upgrade the `Unity.Container` package without having to go down almost every package in all of my projects and upgrade them all.

Comment: "I'd like to know how I can simply upgrade the Unity.Container package without having to go down almost every package in all of my projects and upgrade them all" - that's fundamentally not a *simple* thing to do. If Unity.Container depends on one of your other dependencies, it may well need to upgrade that, or it won't work. That in turn may need to upgrade something else, for exactly the same reason. You say that the package manager feels "very poorly implemented" - how would *you* suggest that inherent complexity is addressed?

Comment: (Basically, versioning is really, really complex. There are plenty of things I would like to see changed (e.g. I'd want the default to allow "upgrade within a major version" rather than "upgrade beyond a major version"), but it's worth acknowledging that it really is a hard problem.)

Comment: I feel like Linux (e.g. Debian) handles it really well by allowing multiple versions of same package to exist side-by-side. I don't feel like Nuget allows this. You might be able to get away with this depending on how you structure your output directories. But if you have a central output directory where binaries land, it's not possible. Throwing installers in the equation further complicates it.

Comment: You can't really compare *application* packages sitting side by side with *libraries* sitting side-by-side. There are things I'd like to see in that space too (in terms of private dependencies) but it's a fundamentally harder problem than applications. The applications aren't all sitting within one process, needing to pass data between different versions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Debian lets me have two versions of libraries installed on my system.

Comment: And can you use both of those library versions *within one process*? That's what you're trying to do within your project. What would you expect to happen if the process wants to pass some data obtained from one of those library versions to a function in a different library version?

Comment: As it relates to my problem, it's a simple matter of allowing me to have two versions of `Unity.AspNet.WebApi` sitting side by side in my output directory. Libraries that need one version get that one, others use the second version.

Comment: "Libraries that need one version get that one, others use the second version." And what if one library passes back a reference to an object from one version to your application, and you want to pass that to a different version of the library? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: I'm not sure if the address space of the application matters. It's a question of what DLLs are loaded as dependencies are resolved. The bigger concern would be if two versions of the same structure get passed between code in the application. But as long as they're private implementations it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think we met in the middle and are identifying a legitimate problem that is hard to solve (but it's at least a choice the programmer makes when they design a library, as opposed to an unavoidable framework/package management issue). We've strayed away from the OP but I definitely hear your point. AFAIK, that concern doesn't apply here.

Comment: There are some possibilities for side-by-side versioning of what I call "private dependencies" but that would be a significant departure for .NET. It could happen at some point, but it's a bigger change than just NuGet... and it wouldn't solve everything, as a lot of dependencies *aren't* private. (For example, NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet has very *public* dependencies on NodaTime and Newtonsoft.Json - that's just the nature of the package.)

Comment: I don't think we've actually strayed from the OP - your question implies that upgrading a single package should be simple, and I'm saying that with the current way the *runtime* and build system (quite aside from NuGet) it's far from simple, and in many cases it *can't* be simple.

Comment: It could be that my question is naive; but I'm at my wits end and I had to ask to see if there's _anything_ I can do. I spent weeks on upgrading these things, tracing issues as I go, and it's been incredibly hard to find out which packages and indirect dependencies are introducing mixed versions of a package. I try to make it all uniform but each upgrade introduces more problems. I just find it hard to believe it's this bad.

Comment: Yes, it *is* this bad, precisely because dependencies are complicated. I would recommend reducing the number of explicit dependencies to as small a set as possible, allowing transitive dependencies to just work. Make all of those dependencies as high as you're happy for them to be, and I'd expect it to *probably* be okay, so long as you're not going across major versions.